# partition device (i.e. /dev/sdd1) not created for hard drive

Tags: linux, partitioning, mdadm

I am having a similar problem as posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/355188/partition-is-missing-in-dev?newreg=54724df32909455a84293800528119a4) where a hard drive has an old mdadm signature on it and the partition on it is not given a device file in /dev

Unfortunately the solution provided in this post won't work.  The system comes back with an access denied error.

I don't see any active mdmon or md processes so I am not sure what process has my device (/dev/sdd in this case) under it's control.

I have tried using udevadm to see if it would identify what has the device locked but I had no success.

Any ideas would greatly appreciated.

Comment: "access denied" errors typically mean you tried to read or write something that your user isn't allowed to. Did you try the operation you're trying to perform as root?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken in the post above.  The computers I installed the drive had automatically "started" a meta-device based on the signature.  I found this out by looking at the /proc/mdstat file.

The command "mdadm --stop /dev/md127" (the meta-device in my case) allowed
the command "mdadm --zero-superblock" to work properly and now the devices are created and the disk partition can be accessed normally.